# Доступ к виртуальному хосту на устройствах без hosts

Tags: веб-сервер, apache, dns

Для работы над проектами создаю вирт.хосты apache под ubuntu, на тестовых машинах прописываю в hosts
192.168.0.5 domain.test
Все хорошо, но сейчас надо проверить проект на мобильниках и планшетах Apple, доступа к hosts без jailbreak на них нет. Как можно на них открыть domain.test?
Из доступных для конфигурирования устройств есть вэб-сервер на ubuntu 12.04, D-Link DIR-300 NRU B5 router

Comment: Теория как это должно быть:  ставить локальный днс и сделать сеть таким образом, чтобы все девайсы, подключенные к сети шли через этот ваш днс сервер.  Если роутер позволяет оверрайдить веб адреса, то можно спокойно сделать на нем.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поднять на убунте dns-сервер, который будет отвечать зоной test, а остальные зоны будет форвардить на 77.88.8.8 или на 8.8.8.8В настройках роутера (точнее, в dhcp) заменить выдаваемый dns-сервер на адрес убунты (или прописать его на время вручную в настройках подключения).

Comment: dnsmasq подойдет для роли маленького DNS-сервера?

Comment: вроде должно подойти

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, как по сети, но в виртуалке сайт доступен просто по IP, и, кажется, я так делал когда-то по локальной сети, если сайт в дефолтной папке var/www

P.S. зашёл с android по локальному ip сервера, всё получилось, но опять же, у меня сайт в дефолтной папке